# Appcelerator : iOS 10 Apple Push Service not working

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, appcelerator, ios10

I'm working with SDK 5.5.1

I'm trying to send APS in production with my own nodejs server.
Everything is working fine with publishing on device in development state. 
I get the device token and the notification is received by the device.

In production, with the same certificate exports (with the production cert and p12), i can get the device token, but not receive the notification.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Here is my tiapp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
<id>app.test.test</id>
<name>test</name>
<version>1.1.2004</version>
<publisher>Zuhn</publisher>
<url>undefined</url>
<description>undefined</description>
<copyright>2016 by Zuhn</copyright>
<icon>appicon.png</icon>
<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
<navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
<analytics>true</analytics>
<guid>mynumber</guid>
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
<property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">true</property>
<ios>
    <team-id>mynumber</team-id>

    <enable-launch-screen-storyboard>false</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
    <use-app-thinning>true</use-app-thinning>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use to your contacts?</string>
            <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use your camera?</string>
            <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use your calendar?</string>
            <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we save to your library?</string>
            <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Can we use your microphone?</string>

            <key>aps-environment</key>
            <string>production</string>

            <!-- Either development or production -->
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
            <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
            <true/>
            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
            <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
            <array>
                <string>voip</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
<mobileweb>
    <precache/>
    <splash>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
    </splash>
    <theme>default</theme>
</mobileweb>
<modules/>
<deployment-targets>
    <target device="android">true</target>
    <target device="ipad">false</target>
    <target device="iphone">true</target>
    <target device="mobileweb">false</target>
    <target device="windows">false</target>
</deployment-targets>
<sdk-version>5.5.1.GA</sdk-version>
<plugins>
    <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
</plugins>
<property name="appc-app-id" type="string">mynumber</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a breaking change from Apple in Xcode 8. You need to create the entitlements file and place it in /app/platform/ios/.entitlements
Example:

> MyApp.entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string> <!-- Either development or production -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23908

Comment: So with SDK 5.5.1 we don't have to fix anything ourselves, yeah?

Comment: With 5.5.1 its fixed and you don't need to change anything anymore I believe

Comment: i didn't get it working on my app,but your answer is correct :) !
I keep trying !

Comment: If you use 5.5.1.GA you no longer need to do this and is working fine for me.