# Confused with apple certificate to publish app and to add push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, titanium, pushwoosh

I want to publish an app for the store (ios), this app should have push notification installed, i am a bit lost with setting the push notification from ios developer panel. 
Here are my steps :

- I create App Id with push notification enabled
- When done, i edit it and add certificate (push certificate)
- i create provisioning profile, with app id
- Finally i have two certificates : Push certificate and Production certificate

I installed production certificate, provisioning profile to keychain, i downloaded push certificate and double click on it to install to keychain.

I build my app, test push and nothing happens, i get error ( no apns-environnement installed) WHYYYYYYYY?????

Please help me, i spend whole day just for it.

I want a step by step help to create production certificate + push certificate, and how to create provisioning profile for both?

Note : for mobile framework i use titanium, and for push : pushwoosh.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Check it :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the link, i already seen it before, i forgot to note that before my push is working good, but i have to change apple account because my client has his own for production, and from there i am not able to setup push.

Comment: @user44321 Try get new certificates of this accaunt.

Comment: also worth making sure you are using titanium SDK 5.5.1.GA  as there is an issue with the entitlements file in a few previous versions, a workaround is on here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824482/appcelerator-ios-10-apple-push-service-not-working/39835437?noredirect=1#comment67233191_39835437